# Opening slidify presentation in RStudio on specific page

Tags: r, slidify

Is there any way to control what page of a slidify presentation the RStudio previewer will open up on? I'd like to be able to preview the page I'm working on, as opposed to the second page of the presentation, where it keeps opening up.

Reprex:

```
library(slidify)
library(slidifyLibraries)
author("test_slides)
```

In the index.Rmd file:

```
---
title       : Yada
subtitle    : Yada-yada-yada
author      : Yoda
job         : 
framework   : revealjs        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
revealjs: {theme: night, transition: convex}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : default 
widgets     : [mathjax]            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
knit        : slidify::knit2slides
---

## Read-And-Delete

1. Edit YAML front matter
2. Write using R Markdown
3. Use an empty line followed by three dashes to separate slides!

--- .class #id

## Slide 2

- Yada

--- .class #id

## Slide 3  

- Yada yada yada

--- .class #id 

## Slide 4

I'd like to open up here!

--- .class #id
```

Comment: other formats do this, for example, use `output: ioslides_presentation` instead of that knit line and your slides will open up on the slide that you left off on. so you could use this format to do your work and revert to slidify at the end for the final product. I don't have a suggestion for slidify specifically

Comment: Thanks @rawr. I've used the ioslides format a bit in the past, and I wanted to learn to use slidify. I'd rather a slidify solution, but thanks for the tip. It'll do for now!